# Spring boot cloud gateway - always 404 except one endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I just want to get the Spring Boot Cloud Gateway running.
I get a result with the following Code with the /get endpoint.

anything else, returns 404. So /test or any other endpoint i add returns 404.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties(UriConfiguration.class)
public class ApigatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApigatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, UriConfiguration uriConfiguration){
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/get")
                        .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
                        .uri(uriConfiguration.getTestUrl()))
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/test")
                        .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
                        .uri(uriConfiguration.getTestUrl()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I followed the tutorial but i have no idea why one endpoint is working and the others not
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like if multiple routes have the same destination URI, you get a 404...